# passing veriable in url weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, php, variables, url

I'm trying to pass a variable throught URL and it's doing something really weird in Chrome and Firefox, it seems is doing the same in OS.

The issue is that I'm trying to send a few variable in the URL this way:

```
document.location.href = 'http://www.ihaves.org/main.php?id='+facebookUser+'&first_name='+facebookName+'&last_name='+facebookName+'&locat='+locat_+'&locationlat='+facebookLat+'&locationlon='+facebookLon+'&mode=facebook';
```

The weird result is this:

> http://www.ihaves.org/Vejer%20de%20la%20Frontera,%20Spain

when the expected result should be this one: (taken from IE)

> http://www.ihaveseen.org/main.php?id=1215834998&first_name=Juanma%20De%20Los%20Santos&last_name=Juanma%20De%20Los%20Santos&locat=Vejer%20de%20la%20Frontera%20Spain&locationlat=36.25&locationlon=-5.96667&mode=facebook

I have detected that the problem is the variable called "locat", if I take it out then everything seems to go fantastic so I have thought that the comma of "Vejer de la Frontera, Spain" might be the problem so I have used:

```
var location_name = locationName.replace(/,/g, '');
```

But it keeps doing the same weird thing than before. Any idea? Does chrome accept an espace beetwen words? Remember firefox does exactly the same.  By the way, I'm using GET_ in the PHP.

Comment: This is what you want to happen.  You should be using encoded key/value pairs.  Some characters will result in an invalid URL.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `encodeURI()` on the Parameters when constructing the URL.

```
document.location.href = 'http://www.ihaves.org/main.php?id=' + encodeURIComponent(facebookUser);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your advise, but I'm sorry to say it keeps doing the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
encodeURIComponent(facebookName)
```

[encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

You should be using encoded key/value pairs.  Some characters will result in an invalid URL. For example:

```
mysite.com?name=Bed&Breakfast
```

will result in two values "`name=Bed`" and "`Breakfast=`" which is not what you would expect or want. Encoding would result in your URL:

```
mysite.com?name=Bed%26Breakfast
```

It may look funny but the URL is now valid and works as expected.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment but no result, any other idea? this is super weird!

Comment: You should be using encoded key/value pairs.  Some characters will result in an invalid URL.

Comment: thanks for your comment and the edition of it. If you have a look to the result in IE (the expected one) I have made some changes, do you see anything wrong? or would you change anything? there's a "-" character that probablly might be the problem, but it would be fantastic if you can have a look to it and tell me what's wrong

Comment: So are you saying the url gets truncated?  And is there supposed to be an underscore after the locat variable: "locat_"?

Comment: No mathius, the url doesn't get truncated, it's seems to be part of stackoverflow posting rules, anyway also the underscore is part of the name of the variable, I mean, is not the value of the variable but the name itself. I can change it to see what happens

Comment: The Locat variable should encode to: Vejer%20de%20la%20Fronter%2C%20Spain using encodeURIComponent the comma being the "%2C"

Comment: The comma is not necessary, I just erased it